# Case when statement within HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

What I tried:-

```
    Select new fully.qualified.classname.ParkingEntry(p.arrivalDate, p.departureDate, 
       (case when p.chargedAmount is NULL then 0 else p.chargedAmount end) as chargedAmount)            
    from fully.qualified.classname.ParkingEntry p
```

Entity ParkingEntry:-

```
@Entity
class ParkingEntry {
    
    Date arrivalDate;
    Date departureDate;
    BigDecimal chargedAmount;
    
    ParkingEntry(Date arrivalDate, Date departureDate, BigDecimal chargedAmount) {
        this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
        this.departureDate = departureDate;
        this.chargedAmount = chargedAmount;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

I am trying to get `arrivalDate`, `departureDate`, and `chargedAmount` from the entity `ParkingEntry` as an Object. I want to ensure the if `chargedAmount` is `null` in the table then it should return the value as 0.
The above query has some syntax errors and hence not working. Any suggestion on how can this be achieved will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try chargedAmount IS NULL instead of = ?

Comment: @DhavalGoti: That's not working as well.

Comment: 1) new requires the fully qualified class name. 2) = NULL is wrong it must bei IS NULL 3) you are selecting from ParkingEntry that is not an Entity

Comment: I have used a fully qualified class name in my actual code and `ParkingEntry` is an entity too and also I have tried `is NULL` with no success. I think it has got something to do with the use of `case` statement within `new ParkingEntry()` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
select new fully.qualified.classname.ParkingEntry(p.arrivalDate, p.departureDate, coalesce(p.chargedAmount, 0))            
from fully.qualified.classname.ParkingEntry p
```